# Regex - Ignore php in <?php

Tags: regex

I try to find all occurences of `<?` on my site to replace them with `<?php` but occurences of `<?php` should be ignored.

Otherwise it would change `<?php` as well and would replace `<?php` with `<?phpphp`

Attempt: `<\?\b(?!php)\b`

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1RPURu/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the word boundaries. You can use the RegEx [`<\?(?!php)`](https://regex101.com/r/1RPURu/2)

- `<\?` matches `<?`
- `(?!php)` makes sure your match isn't followed by `php`

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/1RPURu/2)

Comment: *Note to myself:* You can add more ignore string if you separate them with the pipe `|` e.g.  `<\?(?!php|=)`. This ignores `<?php` and `<?=`.